# Java: Concatinate two XML NodeList

Tags: java, xml, concatenation

I want to concatenate two node lists and get a new node list. At the moment my XML documents look like this:
First XML:

```
<machine>
<values>
<value1> <...> </value1>
<value2> <...> </value2>
</values>

<days>
<value1> <...> </value1>
<value2> <...> </value2>
</days>
</machine>
```

Second XML:

```
<machine>
<values>
<value3> <...> </value1>
<value4> <...> </value2>
</values>

<days>
<value3> <...> </value1>
<value4> <...> </value2>
</days>
</machine>
```

at the moment I am only using one XML with the following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = null;
document = builder.parse(myxml.xml);
NodeList values = document.getElementsByTagName("values");
NodeList days = document.getElementsByTagName("days");
```

and then working on the NodeList with values & days. My program is working fine. Now I create a second list, the same way, so:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder2 = factory2.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document2 = null;
document2 = builder2.parse(myxml_second.xml);
NodeList values2 = document.getElementsByTagName("values");
NodeList days2 = document.getElementsByTagName("days");
```

This raises the question:
**How can I concatenate the two lists, so that I have one list `values` and one list `days`?**

I need a new NodeList (type), cause my whole program works with the NodeList type.

I found several threads to that problem, but nothing works or returns another type but not a NodeList. One method worked:

```
public static NodeList join(final NodeList... lists) {

    class JoinedNodeList implements NodeList {
      public int getLength() {
        int len = 0;
        for (NodeList list : lists) {
          len += list.getLength();
        }
        return len;
      }

      public Node item(int index) {
        for (NodeList list : lists) {
          if (list.getLength() > index) {
            return list.item(index);
          } else {
            index -= list.getLength();
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    }

    return new JoinedNodeList();
  }
```

Then my program works with the concatenated NodeList perfectly but it gets sick slow! I think it comes from the overwriting the two methods, cause I use them a lot in while or for loops. Without the concatenation and only one big list the program is very fast.

Comment: Do you need the `NodeList`s to continue to be dynamic?

Comment: Try col.retainAll(otherCol) // for intersection and 
col.addAll(otherCol) // for union from Collection class and see if there are any improvements

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Dynamic? i dont know what u mean. This codeblock above is called once the programm started and then i just work on with the NodeLists values/days

Comment: @РоманГуйван
And what do you mean with retainAll? can u share a code snippet with my two NodeLists?!

Thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest the following optimisations which may address your "sick slow" issue.

- Compute the length once during construction, as this will not change.
- Flatten the NodeList instances into a primitive array during construction so item() does not have to do as much work.

Assumptions

- Lists are not required to be dynamic, i.e. DOM changes not reflected in lists, this is likely as I don't think results returned by getElementsByTagName() are dynamic anyway
- Documents are relative small so that extra memory isn't an issue.
- There are lots of reads later on meaning extra work during construction has a return on investment.

Code

```
public static NodeList join(final NodeList... lists) {

    int count = 0;
    for (NodeList list : lists) {
        count += list.getLength();
    }
    final int length = count;

    Node[] joined = new Node[length];
    int outputIndex = 0;
    for (NodeList list : lists) {
        for (int i = 0, n = list.getLength(); i < n; i++) {
            joined[outputIndex++] = list.item(i);
        }
    }
    class JoinedNodeList implements NodeList {
        public int getLength() {
            return length;
        }

        public Node item(int index) {
            return joined[index];
        }
    }

    return new JoinedNodeList();
}
```

Comment: Perfect,perfect,perfect. Thank you so much! its even faster than my old version with one list :) And the solution is so simple..

PS: my eclipse only accepts the Node[] joined as final. Why? but it works :)

Comment: @asdf: This was the reason for my question before I went to lunch. :-) (`NodeList` instances are dynamic, meaning that if the underlying document is changed in a way that affects the `NodeList`, you see that change reflected in the `NodeList`. The implementation in your question maintains that, but at a significant cost. Adam's implementation doesn't maintain it, resulting in significant performance gains.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a okay thank you for the explanation! Where kind forum to ask questions, although during my learning google brought me really a lot of times to you :) Thanks!

Comment: @asdf Does this answer fix your problem? Do you need anymore information?